# I am looking for an efficient way to filter dataframe column. Column A is what I have Column B is what I desire

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| A | Output |
| --- | --- |
| All Animals except Tiger/Lion;Elephant;Giraffe;all snakes;monkeys | Elephant;Giraffe;all snakes;monkeys |
| Elephant;All Animals except Tiger/Lion;Giraffe;butterflies;monkeys;humans | Elephant;Giraffe;butterflies;monkeys;humans |
| All Animals except Tiger/Lion;Elephant;Giraffe;all snakes;monkeys | Giraffe;all snakes;monkeys |
| All Animals except Tiger/Lion |  |
| All Animals except Tiger/Lion;Elephant;Giraffe;lions;snake;tiger | Elephant;Giraffe;snake |

I want to strip all the lions, tigers and the text 'All Animals except Tiger/Lion' from the column A

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can split by a semi-colon, filter out the elements containing the text lion or tiger and then put it back together, eg:

```
df['output'] = (
    df['A'].str.split(';', expand=True).stack()
    [lambda v: ~v.str.contains('lions?|tiger', case=False)]
    .groupby(level=0).apply(';'.join)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, I tried it out but on a larger dataset it gave me redundant values in output, I followed a different approach to the problem to solve it.